# chrome extension - page actions for specific pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to add a custom icon to the omni box using the pageAction api

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction

How do I execute custom page actions against specific urls/match patterns only? Is it possible to register events against specific urls?

Example, if user visits foobar.com execute custom page action. For other pages I do not wish to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think `PageStateMatcher` is what you want. [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-PageStateMatcher) here.

such as

```
  new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
    pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'www.google.com', schemes: ['https'] },
    css: ["input[type='password']"]
  })
```

This is the chrome example example *Page action by URL*. Check the `PageStateMatcher` part.

```
// When the extension is installed or upgraded ...
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Replace all rules ...
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // With a new rule ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        // That fires when a page's URL contains a 'g' ...
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlContains: 'g' },
          })
        ],
        // And shows the extension's page action.
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```